# settimeout php sql

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, settimeout

I am using php,sql,javascript I am building a friend request system  , if user-1 sends user-2 a friend request user-2 has 1 hour to accept that friend request or the friend request is automatically denied/removed . . . i can use settimeout to run that function but if the page is refreshed that function is no longer good , I need it to be able to run even if both users are not online anymore . . . so if  user-1 and user-2 are both online at the time when the friend request is sent. . . user-2  and user-1 signs out , i need that friend request to be deleted within 1 hr of the time sent , i am pretty certain that function would need to be ran on the server or something just not sure what direction I would need to look it ! just confused maybe theres a function in php i can use?

Comment: store a timestamp with the initial friend request in the database. Then when you query for any new friend requests, you either add in the where clause `and currentTime < [timestamp + 1 hour]` or run a query to delete any that are over 1 hour old before querying them out. Doing the first option allows you to save a query and then you can just run one query with cron like daily to remove old friend requests.

Comment: make so much sense thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store time in database.
So when user1 send friend request to user2, you'll make request to database and store in table user1_id user2_id request_time.
Than, in some period of time you have to check if

> current time > stored_time + 1 hour
>    
>   If so, remove friend request.

Comment: wow thanks sounds so easy

Answer (score 1):

in addition of what @Grynets said, I would also use a CRON task to automaticly remove the request from the database after the hour. This way you will save alot of place. Imagine that friend 1 never come to check for the request, it will stay in the database.
You can learn more about cron in this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: exactly if they never come back , great add-on ima check it out now . . . thats important